Getting unknown error when updating a document in cloud_firestore using update method
I'm using below code to update a document but getting an unknown error. I have searched through internet and did not find any explanations of this error.
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
String pdtRefId;
await db
    .collection('product')
    .where('pid', isEqualTo: pid)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> value) async {
  print('\nSuccessfully retrieved ordered product');
  pdtRefId = value.docs.first.id;
  
  print('\npdtRefId = $pdtRefId');

  if (pdtRefId.isNotEmpty) {
    try {
      print('Condition met to update, trying now!'); // --> PRINT STATEMENTS IN CONSOLE TILL HERE
      await db.collection('product').doc(pdtRefId).update({"inProd": inProd}); // --> CODE STUCKS HERE

      print('\nUpdate done!!!');

      ref.invalidate(
          FetchProductsProvider(productId: null, clientId: null, inProd: true));
      print('\nInvalidated product provider with inProd: true, awaiting updated view');
      await future;
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      Utils.showSnackBar(error.message);
    }
  }
});

When I run await db.collection('product').doc(pdtRefId).update({"inProd": inProd}); with hardcoded values in an onPressed of Button, below error is shown in console.
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 329:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 265:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7            <fn>


Are you getting any error on firebase console? if so, can you share the error?

I get the above error in terminal when I run/debug flutter app. Its probably not the firebase, I'm missing something.

Solved. Did a silly mistake of not including update rules in firebase.
